# Can't debug Xamarin app because it is a class library

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to debug my Xamarin app (it crashes on `InitializeComponent()` in App.xaml.cs) and I can't get the breakpoints to be hit. I think this is because the app is technically a class library and so I can't set it to be started by the debugger. How can I tell the debugger to debug the main Xamarin app in addition to the Android specific project for the app?

edit: the crash might be related to these designer errors - how do I resolve them?

[image]

Comment: class lib has nothing to do with it.  Are you sure the project has debugging enabled in the active config?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? https://i.imgur.com/ND6xFLF.png

Answer (score 0):

Found this article https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111983/fix-android-resource-designer-cs which recommended I delete my bin and obj folders; doing so fixed the build.